# after version change of the com.onesignal:OneSignal:5.0.3 addSubscriptionObserver showing error

Tags: java, android, onesignal

```
public void checkOneSignal() {
    OneSignal.addSubscriptionObserver(new OSSubscriptionObserver() {
      @Override
        public void onossubscriptionChanged(ossubscriptionstatechanges stateChanges) {
            if (!stateChanges.getFrom().issubscribed() && stateChanges.getTo().isSubscribed()){
                // Get user id
                String one_signal_id = stateChanges.getTo().getUserId();
                String device_id = Settings.Secure.getString(getApplicationContext().getContentresolver(),Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);

                if (device_id!= null && one_signal_id!= null && device_id.length() > 0 && one_signald.length() > 0) {
                    String URL = "https://app.pjani.com/statistics/check_one_signal.php?iddevice=" + device_id + "&idone=" + one_signal_id;

                    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            // Handle the response
                            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            // Handle the error response
                            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });

                    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
                    queue.add(stringRequest);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

this give error on addSubscriptionObserver and getFrom and getTo method in Onesignal library after changing to latest version 5.0.3 when it is in 4.8.6 it works fine but after updating the library this parts are giving error

Comment: What is the error you are seeing?